# NameError: name 'ase' is not defined

Tags: python

```
# Import necessary modules
import numpy as np
from ase.build import bulk
from ase.visualize import view
from ase.atoms import Atoms
from ase import Atoms

# Create a diamond crystal
diamond = bulk('C', 'diamond', a=3.567)

# Create an oxygen atom
oxygen = ase.atoms.Atoms('O', 'fcc', a=3.567)
```

So...the problem is now that this gives an error:

```
oxygen = ase.atoms.Atoms('O', 'fcc', a=3.567)
NameError: name 'ase' is not defined
```

Can anyone help? :/

Comment: you did not actually import ase, literally: import ase

Comment: You're importing `Atoms` from both `ase.atoms` and `ase`. It makes no sense to import the same name from both places, since the second will replace the first.